# Fancybox & JQZoom (and Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, jqzoom

I'm trying to implement a fancybox window that when open will then use JQZoom.

I'm doing this within Wordpress (although I'm not using plugins, so don't know if that impacts anything), and my idea (Option 1) was to load fancybox using an iframe, and then just create another page that implements JQZoom. I couldn't get this to work, but maybe that's because I'm mostly a designer, but maybe I'm doing it wrong...?

Another question on here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994003/adding-zoom-to-fancybox) seemed to imply calling JQZoom when fancybox is fired (i.e., onComplete). I could sort of follow along with what the script was trying to do, but wasn't sure how to implement it.

So I'm wondering what the best way to approach this is.  Option 1, 2, or some other way I haven't thought of?

Fundamentally, I guess what I'm asking is how to combine two JQuery features that are usually called independently, and how does a newbie implement the code to make it work :)

Thanks very much for any advice you may have.